# Unknow file extension with file name "store"

Tags: file

I was trying to reduce some disk space on on my external hard drive and I found a New folder with a file in it. When I opened the folder there was file with the name "store" and no extension. The size of the file is 5.24 GB does anyone know what could it be and is it safe to delete it as I have plenty of data on the External hard drive about 1TB which I cannot loose. please find the screenshot of the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuXk7.jpg)

Comment: (I'm not the down-voter) Does everything else on the drive look fine? And is there any kind of autorun? I don't know enough about drivers and files systems but I'm wondering if maybe the external hard drive isn't being properly recognized.

Comment: Everything is absolutely fine and I have my computer protected by licenced AV with Firewall as well. The external hard drive is always connected to computer and never had any issues of detection or getting disabled.

Comment: I have an AV with firewall and there is no such file by name autorun it has  only. This folder has only one file and nothing else. External had drive is working fine no issues with it

Comment: FYI, SO is for programming questions, not general system maintenance or file identification. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If everything else looks and works fine then I'd just delete it. I'm guessing the file was created by a program, perhaps as temporary storage. To be more cautious you could move the file from your external hard drive to your computer, make sure everything works as expected, then either move the file back or delete it accordingly.

Initially I thought the worst case scenario was that the file was some file system information or driver that your computer wasn't recognizing and deleting it would cause corruption. However since it's always connected to the same computer and all the files etc look fine, the worst thing I can think of is that it's the results of a virus scan or some user settings. Therefore it should be safe to delete.

Side note: in the file properties details tab near the bottom there might be an "Owner" listed although it will probably be (your computer's name) / (your username).